# Need to compare two list and remove item from first list if second list contains same item

Tags: apex, controller

I have a requirement where I need to remove Account from `sObjectList` as my `tempSOjectList` contains account. Below is my code when I try to use `sObjectList.remove(s)` it throws error incorrect signature. What should I do to achieve this?

**Controller**

```
public static List<String> getStandardObjects(String objectName){
    system.debug('objectName ===>>>'+objectName);
    List<string> sObjectList = new List<string>();
    List<string> tempSOjectList = new List<string>();
    tempSOjectList.add('Account');

    sObjectList.add('Account');
    sObjectList.add('Contact');
    sObjectList.add('Lead');
    sObjectList.add('Opportunity');
    sObjectList.add('Case');
    for(string s : sObjectList){
        if(tempSOjectList.contains(s)){
            sObjectList.remove(s);
        }
        update sObjectList;
    }
        return sObjectList;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are much better off using Sets for this sort of thing.

```
Set<String> sObjects = new Set<String>();
Set<String> tempSOjects = new Set<String>();
tempSOjects.add('Account');

sObjects.add('Account');
sObjects.add('Contact');
sObjects.add('Lead');
sObjects.add('Opportunity');
sObjects.add('Case');

sObjects.removeAll(tempSObjects);
```

I note that you apply a DML operation with a list of strings, which is not a valid thing to do.

Comment: I missed out to mention that my method is ```@AuraEnabled``` and I need to return this set to my js, so after trying out your solution it says **set<string> is not supported return type for auraEnabled methods.** Can you suggest something to overcome this?

Comment: Conversion to a list for return is as simple as using `return new List<String>(sObjects);`